# System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException isn't found in namespace

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, nunit, system.text.json

I'm converting a .NET Framework 4.5 project to .NET Core 3.1. My tests used to use Newtonsoft.Json to check if json is valid and now I would want to implement the same with the built-in System.Text.Json. It appears that

```
JsonElement values = JsonDocument.Parse(json).RootElement;
```

throws `System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException`, but I'm unable to catch this as pointing to this exception results in error

> The type or namespace name 'JsonReaderException' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text.Json' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I would just want to understand how is it possible that something that doesn't actually seem to exist can be thrown.

Update #1:
Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8JsonSpan, Utf8JsonReader reader, MetadataDb& database, StackRowStack& stack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 utf8Json, JsonReaderOptions readerOptions, Byte[] extraRentedBytes)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(String json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
   at Anonymized..ctor(String json) in Anonymized.cs:line 182
   at Anonymized.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<TestCreateLogEntryFromJson_IllegalValues>b__0() in Anonymized.cs:line 206
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Throws(IResolveConstraint expression, TestDelegate code, String message, Object[] args)
```

Update #2:
I went to see if there would be some nugets that I'm missing. I found System.Text.Json as a nuget (although it was already accessible, I used System.Text.JsonSerializer successfully within the test file). I added it and now I get the actual problem: It is inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace System.Text.Json
{
    internal sealed class JsonReaderException : JsonException
    {
        public JsonReaderException(string message, long lineNumber, long bytePositionInLine);
    }
}
```

This doesn't however directly solve, how I can catch this within **`Assert.Throws<System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException>`**?

Comment: Can you a stack trace and json sample? Did you remove everything related to `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: Are you sure the `JsonReaderException` is under the namespace `System.Text.Json`? I guess it should be under the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace, please refer this [LINK](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReaderException.htm).

Comment: `JsonReaderException` is a `Newtonsoft.Json` specific exception. You must be still having some dependencies on it as @PavelAnikhouski mentioned.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Do you still think it could be related to Newtonsoft after that stacktrace? Example of an invalid json would be an empty string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that [`System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c19ce52bb6aeb56fb255d7e989eb8471a0aad29a/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/JsonReaderException.cs) is currently **`internal`** indicates that Microsoft may modify or remove this type at any time, and users of `System.Text.Json` should not depend on the continued existence of this class as a subclass of the public [`JsonException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonexception?view=netcore-3.1).  Indeed, the [documentation for `Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) states only that

> When `Utf8JsonReader` encounters invalid JSON, it throws a **`JsonException`** with basic error information like line number and byte position on the line.

And the code comments for `JsonReaderException` state:

> ```cs
> // This class exists because the serializer needs to catch reader-originated exceptions in order to throw JsonException which has Path information.
> ```

**Instead**, assert that the exception thrown is a `JsonException` by using [`Is.InstanceOf<JsonException>()`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/InstanceOfTypeConstraint)

```
Assert.Throws(Is.InstanceOf<JsonException>(), () => JsonDocument.Parse(json).Dispose());
```

If for some reason you **must** assert the specific exception type that was thrown, you could check the exception's full type name by taking advantage of the fact that [`Assert.Throws()`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws) returns the thrown exception:

```
Assert.AreEqual("System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException",
                Assert.Throws(Is.InstanceOf<JsonException>(), () => JsonDocument.Parse(json).Dispose()).GetType().FullName);
```

Or you could use NUnit's [custom constraint mechanism](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Constraints) and introduce a `FullTypeNameConstraint` like the following:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Constraints;

public class FullTypeNameConstraint : Constraint
{
    readonly string expectedFullTypeName;

    public FullTypeNameConstraint(string expectedFullTypeName) : base(expectedFullTypeName) => this.expectedFullTypeName = expectedFullTypeName;

    public override string DisplayName => "FullTypeNameOf";

    public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual)
    {
        var actualTypeName = actual?.GetType().FullName;
        return new ConstraintResult(this, actualTypeName, actualTypeName == expectedFullTypeName);
    }
}

public class Is : NUnit.Framework.Is
{
    public static FullTypeNameConstraint FullTypeNameOf(string expectedFullTypeName) => new FullTypeNameConstraint(expectedFullTypeName);
}   

public static class CustomConstraintExtensions
{
    public static FullTypeNameConstraint FullTypeNameOf(this ConstraintExpression expression, string expectedFullTypeName)
    {
        var constraint = new FullTypeNameConstraint(expectedFullTypeName);
        expression.Append(constraint);
        return constraint;
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to do:

```
Assert.Throws(Is.FullTypeNameOf("System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException"), () => JsonDocument.Parse(json).Dispose());
```

But honestly I wouldn't recommend it.

As an aside, [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1) is disposable and in fact needs to be disposed to free up pooled memory for reuse.

Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0dLxeO.

Answer (score 1):

For xUnit one can use `Assert.ThrowsAny<JsonException>(action)`

Answer (score -6):

You can add `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` to your project references will resolve your issue.